# Issues when using Reflection and IDataReader.GetSchemaTable to create a generic method that reads and processes an IDataReader's current result set

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am writing a class that encapsulates the complexity of retrieving data from a database using ADO.NET. Its core method is

```
private void Read<T>(Action<T> action) where T : class, new() {
    var matches = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<int, PropertyInfo>>();

    // Read the current result set's metadata.
    using (DataTable schema = this.reader.GetSchemaTable()) {
        DataRowCollection fields = schema.Rows;

        // Retrieve the target type's properties.
        // This is functionally equivalent to typeof(T).GetProperties(), but
        // previously retrieved PropertyInfo[]s are memoized for efficiency.
        var properties = ReflectionHelper.GetProperties(typeof(T));

        // Attempt to match the target type's columns...
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) {
            string name = property.Name;
            Type   type = property.PropertyType;

            // ... with the current result set's fields...
            foreach (DataRow field in fields) {

                // ... according to their names and types.
                if ((string)field["ColumnName"] == name && field["DataType"] == type) {

                    // Store all successful matches in memory.
                    matches.AddLast(new KeyValuePair<int, PropertyInfo>((int)field["ColumnOrdinal"], property));
                    fields.Remove(field);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // For each row, create an instance of the target type and set its
    // properties to the row's values for their matched fields.
    while (this.reader.Read()) {
        T result = new T();
        foreach (var match in matches)
            match.Value.SetValue(result, this.reader[match.Key], null);
        action(result);
    }

    // Go to the next result set.
    this.reader.NextResult();
}
```

Regarding the method's correctness, which unfortunately I cannot test right now, I have the following questions:

1. When a single `IDataReader` is used to retrieve data from two or more result sets, does `IDataReader.GetSchemaTable` return the metadata of all result sets, or just the metadata corresponding to the current result set?
2. Are the column ordinals retrieved by `IDataReader.GetSchemaTable` equal to the ordinals used by the indexer `IDataReader[int]`? If not, is there any way to map the former into the latter?

Regarding the method's efficiency, I have the following question:

1. What is `DataRowCollection`'s underlying data structure? Even if that question cannot eb answered, at least, what is the asymptotic computational complexity of removing a `DataRow` from a `DataRowCollection` using `DataRowCollection.Remove()`?

And, regarding the method's evident ugliness, I have the following questions:

1. Is there any way to retrieve specific metadata (e.g., just the columns' ordinals, names and types), not the full blown schema table, from an `IDataReader`?
2. Is the cast to `string` in `(string)field["ColumnName"] == name` necessary? How does .NET compare an `object` variable that happens to contain a reference to a `string` to a `string` variable: by reference value or by internal data value? (When in doubt, I prefer to err on the side of correctness, thus the cast; but, when able to remove all doubt, I prefer to do so.)
3. Even though I am using `KeyValuePair<int, PropertyInfo>`s to represent pairs of matched fields and properties, those pairs are not actual key-value pairs. They are just plain-old ordinary 2-tuples. However, version 2.0 of the .NET Framework does not provide a tuple data type, and, if I were to create my own special purpose tuple, I still would not know where to declare it. In C++, the most natural place would be inside the method. But this is C# and in-method type definitions are illegal. What should I do? Cope with the inelegance of using a type that, by definition, is not the most appropriate (`KeyValuePair<int, PropertyInfo>`) or cope with the inability to declare a type where it fits best?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer a couple of these:

A2) Yes, the column ordinals that come out of `GetSchemaTable` are the same column ordinals that  are used for the indexer.

B1) I'm not sure, but it won't matter, because you'll throw if you remove from the `DataRowCollection` while you're enumerating it in the `foreach`.  If I were you, I'd make a hash table of the fields or the properties to help match them up instead of worrying about this linear-search-with-removal.

**EDIT:**  I was wrong, this is a lie -- as Eduardo points out below, it won't throw.  But it's still sort of slow if you think you might ever have a type with more than a few dozen properties.

C2) Yes, it's necessary, or else it would compare by reference.

C3) I would be inclined to use `KeyValuePair` anyway.

Comment: Regarding your answer to B1), I thought removing elements from a collection inside a `foreach` enumerating it was valid as long as the program doesn't continue to the _next_ iteration. At least, that is how iterators worked in C++.

Comment: Oh, I actually wasn't aware of that.  You're correct.  I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as A1, I believe that until `IDataReader.NextResult()` is envoked, the `GetSchemaTable` will only return the information for the current resultset.

Then when `NextResult()` is envoked, you would have to do a `GetSchemaTable` again to get the information about the current resultset.

HTH.